# Last cell in array that modified

Tags: arrays

Is there any way to find out which cell in an `array` is the last cell that modified? (e.g. change its value)
In any compile-based languages.

For example assume we defined `array1` with `n` cells. Now value of `array1[2]` changed to 1, after that value of `array1[7]` will change to 1, I want a solution to find out the `7th` cell as last cell that modified.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't access the array directly, write to it in a function/method and keep track as it changes. In `C#` there are properties/indexers which wrap the call `X = 2` in a method for you.

Comment: Can you explain it in more details please?

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these seem like particularly great solutions, but they will both accomplish what you want in C++:

```
int indexToChange, lastIndexChanged;
int array1 [10];

indexToChange = 2;
array1[indexToChange] = 1;
lastIndexChanged = indexToChange;

indexToChange = 7;
array1[indexToChange] = 1;
lastIndexChanged = indexToChange;
```

Then at any point array1[lastIndexChanged] would be the most recently updated. But this is annoying since it requires 3 commands for every array update. Instead, you could wrap it into a function:

```
void changeArray(int array[], int length, int indexToChange, int newVal){
   array[indexToChange] = newVal;
   lastIndexChanged=indexToChange;
}
```

Which would then require all your array updates to look like this (assuming `lastIndexChanged` was declared globally and `array1` has size 10):

```
changeArray(array1, 10, 2, 1);
changeArray(array1, 10, 7, 1);
```

Then, to update the most recently changed element to 0:

```
changeArray(array1, 10, lastIndexChanged, 0);
```

However, both of these examples will only work for a single array in a program, which does not seem particularly useful to me.

---

Only other idea I have involves creating an array of tuples (or something similar) and using the 2nd element of the tuple as one of the following:

1. A `bool` flag indicating if the element was the last one changed
2. An `int` flag indicating the "age" of the element

However, both of those methods require accessing every element of the array for every single array update.

For (1), with each update you would have to make sure to find the previously last updated element and set it's flag to `false` as you set the flag of the element you were updating to `true`.

For (2), with each array update you would increment the "age" flag of every element, but set the "age" of the element you updated to `0`. This has the advantage of enabling you to also find the nth last updated element.

In either case, if your original array is an array of ints, you may be able to implement this with a 2-dimensional array with two rows. So, if `array1` is size n, you would have `int array1[2][n]`, giving you an array like this (for n=4, assuming all cells initialized to 0):

```
[0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0]
```

where you would use the top row for your values and your bottom row for flags. Thus, an array update would look something like this:

For "bool" flags (just using 0 and 1 to simulate a bool value):

```
array1[0][2] = 1; //set value of element 2 to 1
array1[1][getLastUpdated()]=false; //resetting the previous "last updated" flag
array1[1][2] = true;
```

For "age" flags:

```
array1[0][2] = 1; //set value of element 2 to 1
for (int i=0; i<array1Length; i++){
    array1[1][i]++; //increment ages of every element
}
array1[1][2] = 0; //reset age of the element you just updated
```

Then, to find the most recently updated element, you would search for `array[1][n]` to be `true` or `0`, respectively.